# How can I tell Wine which output audio device to use?

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio

I'm trying to run games through Wine. However, when the game launches, the sound comes out through my laptop speakers instead of my Bluetooth headphones. To fix this, I tried to alt-tab to the PulseAudio volume control. I can't show it in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFck9.png) because my screenshot button stops working while Wine is running for some reason, but the game shows up in that list. I can set the audio device to my headphones using the drop-down menu, and the game's sound starts coming through my headphones. However, when I alt-tab back to the game, it has usually stopped responding to input. And anyway, having to alt-tab away to the PulseAudio control window each time is annoying.

How can I just tell Wine, in advance, which audio device to use?

Ubuntu 20.04, Wine 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the `PULSE_SINK` environment variable to specify the output device.

First get the names of your speakers:

`pactl list sinks short`

It will look something like this:

```
1   alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
33  alsa_output.pci-0000_2f_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

In my case the names of my two speakers are `alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo` and `alsa_output.pci-0000_2f_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2`. Determine which speaker is your bluetooth headphones and copy the name.

Now launch your wine application with a syntax like this:

`PULSE_SINK="<speaker name goes here>" wine <path to wine application>`

e.g. `PULSE_SINK="alsa_output.pci-0000_2f_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2" wine notepad.exe`

Comment: Yup! Works like a charm.

Comment: @JackM Glad to here it :D Please mark the answer as accepted